# How do the eigenvalues of the Hessian matrix help indicate whether a function $f$ has a minimum or maximum at a point $\vec{a}$?

Tags: proof-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The theorem states: Suppose $f$ is of class $C^2$ at $\vec{a}$ and that $\nabla f(\vec{a})=0$, and let $H$ be the Hessian matrix. For $f$ to have a local minimum at $\vec{a}$, it is necessary for the eigenvalues of $H$ all to be nonnegative and sufficient for them all to be strictly positive. For $f$ to have a local maximum at $\vec{a}$, it is necessary for the eigenvalues of $H$ all to be nonpositive and sufficient for them all to be strictly negative.

How does the value of the eigenvalues $H$ help indicate whether $f$ has a minimum or maximum?

Comment: It gives you the quadratic approximation. What is really going on here is that you're looking at whether $H$ defines a positive-definite, negative-definite, indefinite, or degenerate quadratic form.

Comment: @symplectomorphic  And this is from the characteristic equation right?

Comment: You calculate the eigenvalues from the characteristic equation, yes. But that doesn't tell you *why* the Hessian, and in particular its eigenvalues, controls the behavior of $f$ at a critical point.

Comment: @symplectomorphic so then what did you mean when you mentioned quadratix approximation?

Comment: http://mathinsight.org/taylors_theorem_multivariable_introduction